# Concentration of a modified random walk

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, martingales

Let $\varepsilon$ be a number in $(0, 1)$, consider the following random walk on the real line $X^{(0)}, X^{(1)}, \dots$, where

- $X^{(0)}=0$
- If $X^{(t)} > 0$, then with probability $.5$, $X^{(t+1)} = X^{(t)} + (1-\varepsilon)$, and with probability $.5$, $X^{(t+1)} = X^{(t)} - (1+\varepsilon)$
- If $X^{(t)} < 0$, then with probability $.5$, $X^{(t+1)} = X^{(t)} - (1-\varepsilon)$, and with probability $.5$, $X^{(t+1)} = X^{(t)} + (1+\varepsilon)$
- If $X^{(t)} = 0$, then we do the same thing as the original random walk: with probability $.5$, $X^{(t+1)} = X^{(t)} + 1$, and with probability $.5$, $X^{(t+1)} = X^{(t)} - 1$.

In other words, if $X^{(t)}$ is biased from $0$, we want to "drag it towards $0$," and the strength is controlled by $\varepsilon$.

Is it the case that for nontrivial setting of $\varepsilon$ (for example, $\varepsilon = .3$), that $X^{(t)}$ is well concentrated around $0$  with smaller variance, compared to variance $t$ (thus a deviation of $\sqrt{t}$) in the case of $\varepsilon=0$?

Comment: Isn't it positively recurrent for any $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: I think so, but I am not sure how that would help the estimate of the variance. Maybe there is something in your mind, if so feel free to teach me about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try an answer.
[Edit: simplified and (hopefully) corrected.]

Let $\alpha$ be the only positive solution of $\mathrm{ch}\alpha = \exp(\varepsilon\alpha)$, so that
$$ \exp(\alpha x) = \frac12\left(\exp(\alpha(x+1-\varepsilon))+\exp(\alpha(x - 1 - \varepsilon))\right)\text. $$
The purpose of the definition lies in the fact that $\mathbb E[\mathbf e^{\alpha|X^{(n+1)}|}|\mathcal F_n]=\mathbf e^{\alpha|X^{(n)}|}$ whenever $|X^{(n)}|\geq 1+\varepsilon$. I claim that:

> For $C>0$ large enough, $$\mathbf e^{\alpha|X^{(n)}|}-Cn$$ is a supermartingale.

Indeed, because of the remark above, it is enough to show that for some constant $C>0$, $$\mathbb E[\mathbf e^{\alpha|X^{(n+1)}|}|\mathcal F_n]\leq \mathbf e^{\alpha|X^{(n)}|} + C$$ whenever $|X^{(n)}|< 1+\varepsilon$. This is true for $C=\max\{\mathbf e^{\alpha x},0\leq x\leq 2\}=\mathbf e^{2\alpha}$, for example.

This means that
$\mathbb E[\mathbf e^{\alpha |X^{(n)}|}]\leq 1+Cn$, so $X^{(n)}$ cannot explode that much. For example, about the variance, for any positive exponent $p\in\mathbb N$,
$$   \mathbb E[|X^{(n)}|^2]
\leq \mathbb E[|X^{(n)}|^{2p}]^{1/p}
\leq K\mathbb E[\mathbf e^{\alpha|X^{(n)}|}]^{1/p}
\leq K'(1+n)^{1/p}\text,$$
so the variance increases slower that any root.

---

As Martin pointed out below (thank you!), $\mathbb E[\exp(a|X^{(n)}|)]\leq C'$ whenever $a<\alpha$. It can be seen as a consequence of the modified claim:

> For $C\geq1$ large enough and $\lambda=\mathrm{ch}(a)\exp(-\varepsilon a)$,
>   $$\mathbb E[\mathbf e^{a|X^{(n+1)}|}|\mathcal F_n]\leq \lambda\mathbf e^{a|X^{(n)}|} + C\text.$$

When $X^{(n)}\geq 1+\varepsilon$, this is a consequence of
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\mathbf e^{a|X^{(n+1)}|}|\mathcal F_n]
= & \frac12\left(\exp(a(X^{(n)}+1-\varepsilon))+\exp(a(X^{(n)} - 1 - \varepsilon))\right)\\
= & \mathbf e^{a|X^{(n)}|}\mathrm{ch}(a)\exp(-\varepsilon a)\text,
\end{align*}
and similarly when $X^{(n)}\leq -1-\varepsilon$; when $|X^{(n)}|<1+\varepsilon$,
$$\mathbb E[\mathbf e^{a|X^{(n+1)}|}|\mathcal F_n]\leq\mathbf e^{2a}\text,$$
and the claim follows.

From the claim, and noting that $\lambda<1$, we see that
$$   \mathbb E[\mathbf e^{a|X^{(n)}|}|]
\leq C(1+\lambda+\cdots+\lambda^n)
\leq \frac C{1-\lambda}$$
so $\mathbb E[\exp(a|X^{(n)}|)]$ (hence the variance) is uniformly bounded.

Comment: By essentially the same argument you'll find that $\mathbb{E} \exp(a|X^{(n)}|)$ remains bounded uniformly in $n$ whenever $a < \alpha$.

Comment: Thanks and appreciated. I get the solution. Since I am far from being expert I would like to ask some questions for clarifications: (1) How do you come up with the choice of exp(\alpha|X^{(n)}|)? For a while I was considering supermartingale by transforming |X^{(n)}|, but clearly I failed. Is this related to some consideration of moment generating function? (2) (Just to confirm) Regarding constants here, so \alpha, C only depend on \varepsilon, and K only depends on \alpha and p.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the comment of @martin-hairer. Concerning yours:
(1) I was looking for a function $f$ such that $\mathbb [f_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]=f_n$ ($f_n=f(X^{(n)}$), at least away from the origin. I had the intuition that such a function would grow exponentially, and then the calculations (see above) made the appearance of $\alpha$ clear.

Comment: (2) Yes, $\alpha$ and $C$ depend on $\varepsilon$ only in the first approach, whereas $K$ and $K'$ depend on $\alpha$ (hence on $\varepsilon$) and $p$. In the second, $\lambda$ depend on $\varepsilon$ and $a$, and $C$ depends essentially on $\alpha$ (because $a\leq\alpha$).